# Jenkins + Docker + NPM - Cannot connect to docker:2376

Tags: docker, jenkins, npm

I am trying to follow the tutorial in : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-node-js-and-react-app-with-npm/

I was able to install Docker for windows and run the jenkins container
I get an error when I run the jenkins pipeline:
error during connect: Get https://docker:2376/v1.39/containers/node:6-alpine/json: dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

When I click on the link : https://docker:2376 - I get a response : This site can’t be reached

This is the command I use to run jenkins pipeline:
docker container run --name jenkins-tutorial --rm --detach   --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376   --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1   --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home   --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro   --volume ${HOME}:/home   --publish 8080:8080 jenkinsci/blueocean

Comment: are you running running the docker on a windows machine or linux ? The linked tutorial is using DIND (docker in docker) . If you are running it on linux I recommend do use the docker  from your machine by mapping it to the container: -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock . see link: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337

Comment: I am running the docker on a windows machine. I am using Docker for windows and set the containers to linux

Comment: Ii read a little more and it seems that on windows, in bash terminal the command would be: -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock and in cmd &  powershell just : -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock. The reason is that the extra / stops bash from trying to convert the path to an local windows format. I cannot test this on my machine , so if it works, post it as self answer as it might be helpful to others. PS: welcome to SO !